# Add month in to label

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a object in which i have 2 fields eg: A and B. i want to add month.
for eg: In A = feb and B = May.
so i want feb, mar, apr, may in a label.
The valu of the A and B changes every time.

Can anybody help me to salve this problem.
Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're after and you haven't really asked a question per se, but I think you're looking for picklists. Of each one you could specify the values available (jan through to dec).

Comment: thanks LaceySnr, No the picklists. The I just want o display the months from A to B. If A starts from Feb and B value is May. The display all the months from Feb to May.

Answer (score 0):

Making the presumption that you're using this on a VisualForce page and that your object is called `SomeObject__c` with two Date fields `A` and `B` you could use the following code in your controller.

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    private SomeObject__c obj;

    public string getMonthsLabel(){

        string label = '';
        List<string> months = new List<string>{ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'};

        for(Integer idx = obj.A.month(); idx <= obj.B.month(); idx++)
            label += months[idx-1] + ', ';

        if(label.endsWith(', '))
            label = label.substring(0, label.length()-2);

        return label;

    }

}
```

All you'd need to do then is have an outputLabel in your page that had `value="{!MonthsLabel}"`

Is that what you were looking for?